# Missing Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I installed Visual Studio 2017 recently. Today, when I tried to create a new C++ `Win32 Console Application` project, it shows me the `New Project` wizard again and again. It also displays the following error.

```
Project 'ConsoleApplication8' could not be loaded because it's missing install components. To fix this launch Visual Studio setup with the following selections:
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64
```

I don't know whether this is a pre-existing problem when I installed Visual Studio , because this is the first time that I attempted to create a C++ console app.

I wanted to reinstall Visual Studio, but unfortunately my DVD is broken. So I need to find another solution.

Comment: The solution is to re-run the setup, as the error message says. You're going to have to get another DVD drive or download the installer from MS. There's no magic wand that we can wave that will fix this for you.

Comment: Isn't there any way to download and install Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64 separately?

Comment: No. It's part of the installation. Did you read the words in the error message? *To fix this launch Visual Studio setup with the following selections:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64* That tells you it's part of the setup package and not available separately. If it were available separately,  it would have said *Download this package from this link* instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've finally resolve problem. thanks Ken White to ensure me.
I ran `Setup` then click modify and select following mentioned Items. Then I just wait a few minutes.
[image: Visual Studio C++ core features]

[image: VC++ 2017 v141 toolset(x86,x64)]

Comment: names have changed by 2022, mileage may vary... struggling through it